# google map custom markers in kmlLayer

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have a problem loading the google map custom markers in kmlLayer.
The custom markers become very tiny recently.
http://apdrc.soest.hawaii.edu/gg/rainSD2.php
It was working before.  Does anyone know the problem on that?
Is that the google map API server problem? 
Does google map API change the setting for custom markers size?
Thanks for helping.

Comment: Can you provide a direct link to one of your KML (actually looks like KMZ) files that is being rendered incorrectly?

Comment: here is a direct link: http://apdrc.soest.hawaii.edu/gg/rainSD2/Dry1_a1b_2021-2040.kmz

Answer (score 0):

Google [announced a change to KML rendering](https://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/browse_frm/thread/edde6cb4c6affb7d?hl=en#) that was scheduled to take place in mid-July.  It wouldn't surprise me if this included support of the scale tag.  Are your icons not standard sized?  Should they be scaled?

Looking at your KML, you are scaling your icons:

```
<scale>0.25</scale>
```

If you apply that to your icons which are 32x32, they end up being 8x8, and the dot is already a pretty small chunk of the real estate.

If you change the scale to 1.0, I think it will display as you expect (once the cache on google's servers updates).

Comment: Thanks for your help.  It is weird. I used 0.25 scale before, and it gave me a pretty good scale.  I will change back to 1.0 and check the result. :)

Comment: That wouldn't surprise me, I think it just changed to support the "real" size of the icons, rather than forcing them to be 64x64 (if I remember correctly).  That would have doubled the size of your icons, then if your scale was doing something it would have made it half the actual size 2 * 0.25; now (again assuming it is using the actual size of the icon, it would be half as big as it used to be.  you might need to use 0.5 to get what you had before.